# How to SUM two different Amount_Eur from two different Type_Trans columns SQL

Tags: sql, azure

Here is the table:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Fact_Transactions;
```

[image]

Here is my code to only select two columns as an example:

```
SELECT
    type_trans,
    SUM(Amount_Eur) AS Total_Ins
FROM
    fact_transactions
WHERE
    type_trans IN ('CARD-INCOMING', 'BANK-INCOMING')
GROUP BY
    type_trans;
```

Now, I want to `SUM`` the total.

Thanks in advance!

I tried to sum two amounts from different columns (`Card-Incoming` and `Bank-Incoming`)

Comment: Use `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the scenario in my environment

**IN SQL there is a `CUBE` function**

- The  CUBE  operator generates multiple grouping sets inside a  GROUP BY.
- CUBE  generates  **subtotals**  across all  **column combinations**  specified in  GROUP BY.

**Code Example:**

```sql
SELECT
coalesce([Type_T rans],'Total')  as [Type_T rans],
SUM(Amount_Eur)  AS Total_Ins
FROM
fact_transactions
WHERE
[Type_T rans] IN  ('CARD-INCOMING',  'BANK-INCOMING')
GROUP  BY  CUBE  ([Type_T rans]);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer! I was wondering if I wanted to filter by customer name, should I include it on WHERE clause?